# Score adds 2 points sometimes instead of 1 point

Tags: javascript

I have written a rock, paper, scissor game using javascript. I have got it to play 5 rounds and to keep track of the score every round. However, for some reason every now and then it will add 2 points to the score instead of 1. I am a beginner to javascript and have no idea where I am going wrong. I keep logically going through my loop and don't understand why it does this. How can I stop this from happening?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
let playerScore = 0;
let compScore = 0;
let draw;






/* Players Choice */
  function round() {
  let userInput = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissor?: ');
  console.log(userInput);

  if (userInput == 'rock'){
    console.log(userInput = 1);
  } else if (userInput == 'paper'){
    console.log(userInput = 2);
  } else if (userInput == 'scissor'){
    console.log(userInput = 3);
  }


/* Computers Choice */
  let compMove = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
  console.log(compMove);

  if (compMove == 1) {
    alert('Rock!');
  } else if (compMove == 2){
    alert('Paper!');
  } else if (compMove == 3){
    alert('Scissor!');
  }

return {
  compMove,
  userInput
};

};




/* Compare */
function result(compMove, userInput) {
  if (compMove == 2 && userInput == 1) {
    alert('You lose!');
    compScore += 1;
  } else if (compMove == 3 && userInput == 1){
    alert('You Win!');
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 2){
    alert('You Win!');
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 3){
    alert('You Lose!')
    compScore += 1;
  } else if (compMove == userInput){
    compScore;
    playerScore;
  }

  return {
    compScore,
    playerScore
  };
}



function game() {
  for (let i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
  let roundNumber = round();
  result(roundNumber.compMove, roundNumber.userInput);
  console.log(result(compScore, playerScore));

};

return {
  compScore,
  playerScore
};

};


console.log(game());

if (playerScore > compScore) {
  alert('You Won the Best of 5!');
} else if (playerScore < compScore) {
  alert('You Lost.')
} else {
  alert('It is a Draw!');
}
```

Comment: Inside game method you've called result() twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made calls to `result()` twice in game(). Store the result() in a 
`const` and put that in console.log.

Also, in the result function, you haven't really covered all the possibilities of outcomes by computer and the user. You should cover the cases where `userInput` is 2 and `compMove` is 3, also where `userInput` is 3 and `compMove` is 2.